# Issue with mdmysql.Parameters.AddWithValue for string value

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services

When I try to insert a string value using `mdmysql.Parameters.AddWithValue` it generates an input format string exception. Following is the code which produces the error:

```
cmdmysql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_mode", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "ccc";
```

I tried with `varchar`, `string`, `text` but nothing is working. Also if I put `null` in place of "ccc" then the record gets inserted into the table. The variable type for `p_mode` in table is `varchar`. What is the reason for this exception?

Comment: You are attempting to assign string to number or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddWithValue` function takes only two inputs, 1. The parametername and 2. the value

```
cmdmysql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_mode", "ccc");
```

If you want to use the definition of types you must use the normal `Add` function:

```
cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_mode", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "ccc";
```

I would guess that the exception comes from your second input where you parse an `MySqlDbType` to the function and not the acutal value you want the returned mysqlparameter to have.

Comment: thnx the one with addvalue is working, but the other with add is giving the same error

Comment: thnx it is working now with addwithvalue but giving same error if i use add

Comment: Can you show use some more code to set it into context and possibly also show the table structure, just the create statement for the table you insert into?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cmdmysql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_mode","ccc");
```

Comment: No! this is not answer. "CCC" is string constant.

Comment: thnx it is working now with addwithvalue but giving same error if i use add